# Does Cubic Gauche Nitrogen Exist Anywhere in the Universe?

Tags: thermodynamics

This question has been somewhat *pre-empted* by a report of its synthesis! They say "green energy storage material" (not quite verbatim) ... yeah - & superpowerful explosive as well - you can be sure that's going to be it's *first* use!

But the *synthesis* is not what I am concerned with here, and does not count towards meeting the purport of this question.

Basically it's a (formerly) hypothetical allotrope of nitrogen with an *extremely* high heat of formation - puts lead azide in the shade - possibly indeed absolutely the highest heat of formation attainable by *any* chemically bonded substance atall. But it requires 110GPa & 2000K; and I wondered whether natural conditions could *ever possibly* arise *anywhere* such that a piece of this could form in the first place *and then* survive destruction through it's being so *very very* brisant ... whether basically there's *any* piece of it floating around *anywhere* in space. Obviously if it is somehow formed deep within a body of rock, is it *atall* plausible that it might somehow be extricated from it without it detonating? Or could some *extremely*  fortuitous constellation of conditions arise whereby it could be formed & not *have* to be extricated from anything? Is the *synthesised* piece of this stuff the first that has *ever* existed?

The guys who synthesised it somehow circumvented the extreme pressure & temperature requirements. After all, CVD diamond is made circumventing the T & P requirements for *that* substance, and is now a standard (though fabulously expensive) industrial process.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  Looks like you basically want to answer your own question, which is allowed, just the question statement should still just be the question itself, and then you write up the answer in response to your own question separately.  I'd suggest that you edit your question statement above to just be a question, then you can put your answer to it below.

Comment: I'm not qruite sure that's _quite_ so: the question is _essentially_ "might it possibly exist _naturally_ this report (truly remarkable & unexpected by me) is not _really_ comprised in the ambit of the question, and is mentioned here merely as a sort of ... appendix, if you will. Stil, I have only just started here; and please don't take this as a _rejection_ of your advice: I am open to being coached in the _etiquette_ of this forum.

Comment: Can you not edit comments? That one has some _appalling_ typos. "

Comment: Generally speaking, if it is formed under certain conditions then it is likely stable under those conditions. Remove it from those conditions though, and all bets are off. The hype in the question is not needed, however...

Comment: Right - thanks! 'T's too late for _that_ one then! Not That it matters a great deal.

Comment: @Jon Custer -- According to theory of it, it _is_ metastable ... and susceptible to detonation. The question would I think better be "is there a _free_ naturally occuring piece of it ... ?". The rationale of question is that it seems to me that for the conditions of temperature & pressure to come about, _and_ then for it to _become free_ without detonating and a piece of it to be floating about in space or sitting on the surface of a solid celestial object is a scenario that is _on the very cusp_ of plausibility. I _very_ much doubt there's enough of it anywhere to show-up on any spectroscope.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'hype' - I would guess that you are referring to the little dig at the preponderance of the _military_ in driving innovation. Is this forum then really so _very_ austere, in that it is not customary to make even so little an aside as that? It's a _bona fide_ question, by the way - absolutely _not_ meant sarcastically.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites aren't actually forums. They're more like wikis, organised in a question & answer format. So we try to keep the tone objective, similar to what you expect to see in a Wikipedia article. However, we also have chat rooms, where things are a little more relaxed, and subjective opinions are more welcome (as long as they are expressed politely, of course).

Comment: I use the word 'forum' very loosely to mean _this online question/answer/comment arrangement_. I do take it then that it's _not_ customary to embellish a post or answer with ... say, a _swipe_ at the military provenance of something, or that kind of thing! Thank-you for your advice.

Comment: ... embellish a _post_ or _answer_ or comment ... I sometimes use these terms a bit loosely or interchangeably. _Embellish __input___.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would say that there is *none* of this stuff in nature *anywhere* in the universe, having thought about it for a while. Except *just possibly* buried deep down in something - *not* floating around in space, or lying on the surface of any celestial body. It's said to be *exceedingly* easily detonated, (although how they calculate these things I don't know - I think the calculation of properties of hypothetical substances is one of those *astonishing* accomplishments - do they solve the *Schroedinger equation* for the complete ensemble!?),  and space is just too *violent* a place for such a substance *ever* to be extricated from the matrix in which it forms without detonating.

Comment: Apologies please that wasn't meant to go in - I was just trying to work something out for something else & I hit _submit_ rathef than _preview_ by accident. I'll delete it at once.

Comment: Right - I've got the right answer in the right place now.

Comment: Compounds with a high proportion of nitrogen tend to be *vigorously* unstable. Derek Lowe wrote an entertaining article on this topic a few years ago: [Things I Won’t Work With: Azidoazide Azides, More Or Less](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2013/01/09/things_i_wont_work_with_azidoazide_azides_more_or_less)

Comment: I thought, what with it being _pure nitrogen_, if some nitrogen should somehow get trapped in some rock, maybe at first at low enough temperature for it to be solid (& apparently _there is __ordinary___ solid nitrogen lying around), then there be accretion on top to the tune of 110 GPa, then _somehow_ it get heated to 2000K (the requisite conditions, according to the theory); and then - and this is the hardest bit - that matrix be _everso gently_ eroded away ... that there _just just __might___ be some lying or floating around.

Comment: He certainly _will_ work with them of course ... 't'swhat he _lives for, _init_!?

Comment: There seem to be a few compounds with that _empirical_ formula having similarly explosoferic properties. There must be some j

Comment: kind of _niche_ of relative stability at that particular composition.